# dynamic ffserver authentication

Tags: video, ffmpeg, authentication, video-streaming, html5

Ideally I'd like to just be able to add/remove a list of session keys to/from a text file stored on the server without restarting the ffserver instance, but am open to other solutions such as proxies - ffserver streams must be accessible from the HTML5 video tag and any password/sessionkey must be sent after the handshake has begun.